# When / How to stop Ruby loop that creates nested arrays within nested arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I'm unsure when to end the loop that runs the map statement, the times is simply put in place as an example of where the loop should be and what code should be contained within. I would like to run it until the first value of the created multidimensional array is 0 (because it will consistently be the largest value until it becomes 0 itself and creates the last nested array), but I'm completely stumped on how to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def wonky_coins(n)
    coins = [n]
    if n == 0
        return 1
    end
    i = 1
    n.times do 
        coins.map! do |x|
        if x != 0
            i+= 2 
        else
            next
        o = []    
        o << x/2 
        o << x/3 
        o << x/4
        x = o
        puts x
        end
        end
    end
        return i
end

wonky_coins(6)
```

Problem:

```
# Catsylvanian money is a strange thing: they have a coin for every
# denomination (including zero!). A wonky change machine in
# Catsylvania takes any coin of value N and returns 3 new coins,
# valued at N/2, N/3 and N/4 (rounding down).
#
# Write a method `wonky_coins(n)` that returns the number of coins you
# are left with if you take all non-zero coins and keep feeding them
# back into the machine until you are left with only zero-value coins.
#
# Difficulty: 3/5

describe "#wonky_coins" do
  it "handles a coin of value 1" do
    wonky_coins(1).should == 3
  end

  it "handles a coin of value 5" do
    wonky_coins(5).should == 11
    # 11
    # => [2, 1, 1]
    # => [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
    # => [[[0, 0, 0], 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
  end

  it "handles a coin of value 6" do
    wonky_coins(6).should == 15
  end

  it "handles being given the zero coin" do
    wonky_coins(0).should == 1
  end
end
```

Comment: to stop a loop you just use the `break` command. To skip to the next element without stopping the entire process, use the `next` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not have nested arrays. You want to flatten the array after each pass, so you just have coins; even better, use `flat_map` to do it in one step. `0` produces just itself: `[0]`; don't forget it or your code will lose all of your target coins!

Next, there is no logic to doing it `n` times that I can see. No fixed number of `times` will do. You want to do it `until` all coins are zero. You can set a flag at the top (`all_zero = true`), and flip it when you find a non-zero coin, that should tell your loop that further iterations are needed.

Also, you don't need to track the number of coins, since the number will be the final `size` of the array.

And finally, and unrelated to the problem, do get into the habit of using correct indentation. For one thing, it makes it harder for yourself to debug and maintain the code; for another, bad indentation makes many SO people not want to bother reading your question.

Answer (score 0):

Went back a bit later now knowing about how to use .flatten and I got it! Thanks to @Amadan for the helpful tips. Feel free to leave any comments concerning my syntax as I am just starting out and can use all the constructive feedback I can get!

```
def wonky_coins(n)
    coins = [n]
    return 1 if n == 0
    until coins[0] == 0
        coins.map! { |x|
            next if x == 0 
            x = [x/2, x/3, x/4]
        }
        coins.flatten!
    end
    return coins.length
end

wonky_coins(6)
```